# sitemap.xml on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, web, search-engine, web-crawler, yaml

I have the following yaml file for my Google App Engine website.

```
application: <my-app-id>
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /sitemap.xml
  static_files: static/sitemap.xml
  upload: static/sitemap.xml

- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

When I test this app using the local server, the file sitemal.xml is accessible by navigating to.

```
 http://localhost:8080/sitemap.xml
```

However, when I deploy the app, navigating to the following page just redirects me to index.html (it is impossible to download the xml file).

```
 http://<my-domain>.net/sitemap.xml
 http://www.<my-domain>.net/sitemap.xml
```

Why is the local version behaving differently from the deployed version? What can I do to make the file available in the deployed version?

Comment: Is yourdomain.net a redirect to www.yourdomain.net by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine [doesn't support naked domains](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#naked_domain) and most likely it's not being redirected correctly. Try accessing it via: `http://www.<my-domain>.net/sitemap.xml` to see if that works.

Comment: No, it doesn't make a difference whether I use it with or without www subdomain. Either way, I can't access the file.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was caused by domain redirection. If I access the application directly, via the following.

```
http://<app-id>.appspot.com/
```

Then everything is fine. Apparently something is broken in the way the domain hosting service handles the redirection.